# Need guidance of Graphing a set of complex umbers with Argument.

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to give a graph represantation of the next set $$
A=\left\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Arg}\left(i(z-6)^2\right)=\frac{\pi}{6}\right\}
$$

first i caclulate which complex numbers z have Argz=π/6 ,And I construct the half-line starting from the origin of the coordinate axes, forming an angle of π/6 (30 degrees), and continue working on this .$$
B=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \operatorname{Arg} z=\pi / 6\}
$$
after that $$
C=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: i z \in B\}
$$
If I want iz to belong to set B, it means that the position of iz is the same as the initial half-line, but rotated 90 degrees clockwise. From that point, by multiplying complex numbers by i, the complex numbers are in set B. Therefore, I have the half-line forming an angle with the axis of π/6 - π/2 = -π/3 radians. my problem is what is going on with the second power.. i know that if we have a complex number z .. z^2 going to have  double the magnitude and double the principal argument. So, I think I need to halve the angle I currently have and take -π/6. What should I do next? I would also like to know if there is a specific approach to these problems, i.e., in which order should we consider and explore the terms?

After that, what should I do? I would also like to know if there is a specific approach to these problems, meaning in which order should we take and explore the terms?
Would the same principles apply to this set as well?$$
A=\left\{z \in \mathbb{C}:|A r g(i z+1)|=\frac{\pi}{3}\right\}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your general process is good. Just work backwards, step by step. Drawing pictures for each intermediate set ($B$, $C$, $D$, etc.) helps too (unfortunately, I can't show them to you).

There's no hard rule on the order in which you unravel the compositions, but usually there's one that most easily identifiable. You should try to make it as explicit as possible. For the first problem, I took $z \mapsto z - 6 \mapsto (z - 6)^2 \mapsto i (z - 6)^2 \mapsto \text{Arg}(i (z - 6)^2)$.

You have already worked out that $C = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \text{Arg}\ z = -\pi/3\}$. Now you want to find $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: z^2 \in C\} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \text{Arg} \ z^2 = -\pi/3\}$. Here, you need to be careful, as the complex phase/argument is only unique up to integer multiples of $2\pi$.

Consider a non-zero complex number in polar coordinates: $z = \rho e^{i\theta}$, $\rho > 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
z \in D & \Leftrightarrow z^2 = \rho^2 e^{2i \theta} \in C\\
& \Leftrightarrow \text{Arg}(z^2) = \text{Arg}(\rho^2 e^{2i \theta}) = -\pi/3\\
& \Leftrightarrow 2\theta = -\pi/3 + 2k\pi, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}\\
& \Leftrightarrow \theta = -\pi/6 + k\pi, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.
\end{align*}
Here, up to $2\pi$, there are two distinct phases: $-\pi/6$ and $-\pi/6 + \pi = 5\pi/6$. So $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \text{Arg} \ z = -\pi/6 \ \text{or} \ 5\pi/6\}$. It consists of two rays emanating from the origin. One going at phase angle $-\pi/6$, the other in the opposite direction, at phast angle $5\pi/6$.

Finally, $A = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: z - 6 \in D\}$, which is just $D$ shifted to the right by $6$ units.

As for $A = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |\text{Arg}(iz + 1)| = \pi/3\}$, also do it step by step. First, let's break down the composition: $z \mapsto iz \mapsto iz + 1 \mapsto \text{Arg}(iz + 1) \mapsto |\text{Arg}(iz + 1)|$. So we begin by unraveling the last layer in the composition - the $|\cdot|$ sign. That is, simplify $B = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |\text{Arg} \ z| = \pi/3\} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: \text{Arg} \ z = \pm \pi/3\}$.